# How to use an audio stream that can be null in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I want to take the audio from a video, set it's volume, and join them back (with some more filters, but I don't think they are relevant to the question.)

I can do it with:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.5[a0];[a0][1:a]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[audio]" -map v:0 -map "[audio]" -shortest out.mp4
```

But, the video not have an audio stream and then I get Error: `Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:a]volume=0.5[a0] matches no streams.`

How can use the stream conditinally if not null? (In case it's null, I want to have empty audio).

Comment: May the answers on this question may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853117/how-to-detect-audio-or-video-or-both-exist-in-converted-file

Comment: @RicardoBohner thx, but I was looking for 1 command solution. If I wont find, I think that's that what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

> with some more filters, but I don't think they are relevant to the question

Since you haven't shown your actual full command, I can only answer below for the command you posted, which may not be applicable for the full command.

---

Switch to a simple filtergraph for the audio, with conditional mapping.

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:a? -filter:a:0 "volume=0.5" -shortest out.mp4
```

Comment: See edit. I must using filter complex too. I get: Filtergraph 'volume=0.5' was specified for a stream fed from a complex filtergraph. Simple and complex filtering cannot be used together for the same stream.

Is there a solution to conditionally select stream in -filter_complex?

Comment: Or to conditionally add `anullarc` instead if not present audio?